# Scheduling in play framework: increasing thread number

Tags: multithreading, scala, playframework, akka

I have a simple task in my service (play 2.5.4):

```
@Singleton
class BalanceService @Inject()(val contexts: Contexts, as: ActorSystem) {

    private val after = FiniteDuration(5, SECONDS)
    private val interval = FiniteDuration(5, SECONDS)

    private val checkBalanceTask = as.scheduler.schedule(after, interval) {
        logger.debug(s"BalanceUpdate")
    }(contexts.miscCtx)

...
```

Where **contexts.miscCtx** is a custom defined context (in application.conf) like

```
misc {
    fork-join-executor {
      parallelism-factor = 1
      parallelism-max = 24
      task-peeking-mode = LIFO
    }
  }
```

So every time the task is executed, I get a line in the log:

```
17:26:44.128 [application-contexts.misc-65  ] DEBUG model.services.BalanceService - BalanceUpdate
17:26:49.128 [application-contexts.misc-66  ] DEBUG model.services.BalanceService - BalanceUpdate
17:26:54.129 [application-contexts.misc-67  ] DEBUG model.services.BalanceService - BalanceUpdate
```

The thread number is constantly increasing, but **total number of threads is the same** (I checked with a profiling tool). What may be wrong with my settings? Seems like threads created and destroyed each time instead of reusing old ones.

Comment: what if the threads are just used in a round-robin fashion? have you verfieid that?

Comment: @rethab Yes, I checked, a count went up to 15000+

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `thread-pool-executor` rather than `fork-join-executor`.

Comment: Regardless that your answer is correct (assuming that there is some threads with manageable block, so new threads are created to steal job from them) , it's better to explain and provide some links

Comment: I created a totally new context misc2 only for that single job:
misc2 {
    thread-pool-executor {
      fixed-pool-size = 2
    }
  }
Still got
19:10:03.108 [application-contexts.misc2-149] DEBUG model.services.BalanceService - BalanceUpdate
19:10:08.109 [application-contexts.misc2-150] DEBUG model.services.BalanceService - BalanceUpdate

Comment: Strange, but using ExecutionContext.fromExecutor(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1)) helps